# change colours in styles.xml that are set in colors.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, colors, styles

I have custom colors set in my colors.xml as per below, however, is it possible to change/update the color in my styles.xml theme node as per below;

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>
    <color name="themeBackground">#000000</color>
    <color name="darkColor">#000000</color>
    <color name="lightColor">#ffffff</color>
<resources>
```

and change manually in my **v21\styles.xml** as per below as is used in

```
//used in activity
onCreate().setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
```

**v21\styles.xml**

```
<style name="DarkTheme">
    <!-- change themeBackground manually here -->
    <item name="themeBackground">@color/darkColor</item>
</style>

<style name="LightTheme">
    <!-- change themeBackground manually here -->
    <item name="themeBackground">@color/lightColor</item>
</style>
```

I have tried this but have no luck as only seems that android values can be changed i.e

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/lightColor</item>
```

Comment: So, you want dynamic themes. Is that right?

Comment: You could say that, but just thought this could be the easiest option by setting additional default custom colors but then change them per setTheme();recreate(); ..instead of doing the longer way via theme.xml which I have not yet tried ...

Comment: via theme.xml as per https://medium.com/@vinitagrawal91/android-colors-and-multiple-themes-fdfca3f75a15

Comment: XML styles are immutable. You can not change them on the fly. After setTheme you could call activity.recreate() to see the effect. onCreate().setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme); does not work.

Comment: yes but with custom color changes being reset/changed in multiple <style name="DarkTheme"> nodes, simple running setTheme();recreate(); could effectively process the changes on the fly. However I seems only via values/theme.xml & values/attrs.xml will this be possible which is just a bit extra coding...

Comment: unless custom colors are not accessible in theme.xml as well...

Comment: Ended up theming via values/theme.xml & values/attrs.xml. Also had to remove duplicate theme from the v21\styles.xml as I was getting runtime errors

Comment: @BENN1TH can u post a full answer, your approach sounds interesting

Comment: see posted answer, with help from https://medium.com/@vinitagrawal91/android-colors-and-multiple-themes-fdfca3f75a15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had success (not fully tested) changing the background via the below using ***values\themes.xml*** & ***values\attrs.xml*** + ***values\colors.xml***

**`*Ensure any themes created in values\styles.xml are not duplicated in themes.xml (i.e same key name <style name="LightLoginThemeV3">)*`**

added below to **values\colors.xml** *(should already exist ...)*

```
<!-- light Theme colors -->
<color name="lightBackgroundPrimaryV3">@color/white</color>
<color name="lightBackgroundSecondaryV3">@color/lighter_grey</color>
<color name="lightBackgroundAltV3">@color/lighter_grey</color>
<color name="lightBackgroundAltAlphaV3">#809E9E9E</color>
<color name="lightBackgroundLightV3">#80FFFFFF</color>
<color name="lightThemePrimaryColourV3">#01aac4</color>
<color name="lightThemeSecondaryColourV3">#025f8b</color>
<color name="lightThemeDarkPrimaryColourV3">@color/white</color>
<color name="lightThemeDarkSecondaryColourV3">@color/lighter_grey</color>

<!-- dark Theme colors -->
<color name="darkBackgroundPrimaryV3">#241e45</color>
<color name="darkBackgroundSecondaryV3">#2f2856</color>
<color name="darkBackgroundAltV3">#483e81</color>
<color name="darkBackgroundAltAlphaV3">#80483e81</color>
<color name="darkBackgroundLightV3">#f4f3f3</color>
<color name="darkThemePrimaryColourV3">#01aac4</color>
<color name="darkThemeSecondaryColourV3">#025f8b</color>
<color name="darkThemeDarkPrimaryColourV3">#2f2856</color>
<color name="darkThemeDarkSecondaryColourV3">#50448f</color>
```

**values\attrs.xml** *(create attrs.xml in values folder if non-existent)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- background color keys -->
    <attr name="basePrimaryBackgroundColour" format="reference|color"/>
    <attr name="baseSecondaryBackgroundColour" format="reference|color"/>

</resources>
```

**values\themes.xml** *(create attrs.xml in values folder if non-existent)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="LightLoginThemeV3">

        <!-- keys from values/attrs.xml file -->
        <!-- background color keys -->
        <!-- using light Theme colors via @color -->
        <item name="basePrimaryBackgroundColour">@color/lightBackgroundPrimaryV3</item>
        <item name="baseSecondaryBackgroundColour">@color/lightBackgroundSecondaryV3</item>

        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/backgroundSecondaryV3</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/backgroundSecondaryV3</item>

        <!-- EditText Fields -->
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/medium_grey</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/themePrimaryColourV3</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/themePrimaryColourV3</item>

    </style>

    <style name="DarkLoginThemeV3">

        <!-- keys from values/attrs.xml file -->
        <!-- background color keys -->
        <!-- using dark Theme colors via @color -->
        <item name="basePrimaryBackgroundColour">@color/darkBackgroundPrimaryV3</item>
        <item name="baseSecondaryBackgroundColour">@color/darkBackgroundSecondaryV3</item>

        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorTrans</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/darkist_grey</item>

        <!-- EditText Fields -->
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/dark_grey</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

and in my related layout file, set background like so ...

```
 //key from values/attrs.xml file
 android:background="?attr/basePrimaryBackgroundColour"
```

and in my activity onCreate() method (and onResume() method), set theme from values\themes.xml via below on the fly ...

```
if(darkTheme){
    setTheme(R.style.DarkLoginThemeV3);
}else{
    setTheme(R.style.LightLoginThemeV3);
}
```

and in my activity, via a clickListner event, changetheme from values\themes.xml via below on the fly ...

```
if(darkTheme){
    setTheme(R.style.DarkLoginThemeV3);
    recreate();
}else{
    setTheme(R.style.LightLoginThemeV3);
    recreate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to apply theme at runtime. One of them has been very well covered [here](https://medium.com/mindorks/mastering-android-themes-chapter-4-591e03320182). The problem with these approaches is that you will have to recreate the activity at least one by calling [`recreate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()). But you may encounter a scenario where recreating activity is not feasible, may be due to its dependence on data or inefficiencies of an existing architectural pattern.

There are also some other ways that would work as well without recreating activity: recursively finding views and applying theme. To be able to do that, the first constraint is to have all custom views.

For every framework view or viewgroup, define custom view like below example:

```
class CustomTextView extends AppCompatTextView {}
```

Now you will need an interface like below example that can be implmeneted in the view and triggered while changing theme dynamically.

```
interface Painter {
  void applyTheme(int theme)
}
```

Implement that in your custom view class like below :

```
class CustomTextView extends AppCompatTextView implements Painter {
     @Override
     public void applyTheme(int theme) {
          switch (theme) { ... }
     }
}
```

And somewhere in your activity, recursively find views which implements `Painter` and trigger `applyTheme` like below :

```
public void onChangeThemeClick(int selectedTheme){
     View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
     paintRecurively(rootView,selectedTheme);
}

public void paintRecurively(View view, int theme) {
   //if view implements painter, trigger the method
   if(view instanceof Painter){
     (Painter)view.applyTheme(theme);
   }
   //if view is viewgroup then further call this method for its children.
   if(view instanceof ViewGroup){
      ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)view;
      for(...childCount of vg){
          paintRecurively(vg.getChildAt(i),theme);
      }
   }

}
```

This may sound like a lot of work. But, you will have to do only if you don't want to recreate activity.

Comment: Well aware of the recreate() method and its restrictions as you have stated.

Comment: Ok. I thought it would be good to keep both ways here for reference.